# create controllers in subfolders in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

i need to put admin controllers in subfolder like this
app\controllers\adpanel\AdminsControllers.php
also put view in subfolder like this:
app\views\adpanel\login.php
app\views\adpanel\dashboard.php

is this possible?what should i do?

Comment: Yes, you can use 'controllerMap' into your condig/main.php read the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#controller-map)

Comment: i use yii2 basic i have config/web.php.i dont know how to use 'controllerMap'

Comment: I don't remember in what part of documentation it's explained, but read carefully and you will find. config/web.here you can set

Comment: You also can configure an use modules instead of mapping controllers in sub folders, you will achieve a better structure and keep all clean https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-modules